# How manage state of unknown number of text areas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have used map function and assigned values to the `textarea` using value and also tried to assign with `defaultValue`.

But if I use value then I cannot change the value in onChange function and if I use defaultValue then the same value is appearing for other values.

```js
// Update value
this.props.values.map((item: any) => (<TextArea onChange={this.handleChange} value={item.val}/>))

// Update defaultValue
this.props.values.map((item: any) => (<TextArea onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue={item.val}/>))
```

I expect to change the `textarea` value to new value if required.

Comment: you can change by using OR operator value={item.val ||  your new state value }/>))

Comment: glad that i could help ,if that works kindly upvote the answer

Comment: this is working if the value inside the text area is empty but if there is value already existing then I cannot able to change it.

Comment: need to see handleChange function code

Comment: ```private handleChange = (e: any) => {
        this.setState({newVal: e.target.value})
    }```

Comment: `value={item.val || this.state.newVal}/>))` it doesn't work ?

Comment: no it doesnt work. I cannot modify the value

Answer (score 1):

You need to manage the **value state** of every `Input` component which mapped.

Theoretically, you want to make `N` states as `N` area text boxes, one way to do so it to manage a **single object** which contains all states.

> The answer is written with hooks, it's pretty easy to make equivalent one with a class component.

```js
// props.values
const VALUES = ["Hello", "World", "All Texts Areas Managed"];

function TextAreaManager() {
  // We will manage text box i
  const [valuesManager, setValuesManager] = useState([...VALUES]);
  return (
     {VALUES.map((value, i) => (
       <TextBoxItem
         key={i}
         value={valuesManager[i]}
         onChange={e => {
           // Update the value of text box i on next render.
           valuesManager[i] = e.target.value;

           // Render with new value of text box i.
           setValuesManager([...valuesManager]);
         }}
       />
     ))}
  );
}
```

Demo:

[image: Edit bold-sun-9mn3v]

Comment: How can I achieve this with out hooks?

Comment: There is no much difference of how to manage state with hooks and classes, you want to see the same example with classes?